# How to Loadbalance Outgoing Traffic with Iptables?

Tags: centos, iptables, centos7, load-balancing, centos6

I have a centos 7 server with 5 IPS like 192.168.0.2/29 to 192.168.0.5/29.I want to change Outgoing traffic in roundrobin method because i need to use all ips to my project. so am trying to configure iptables with the command

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.1/29 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.3
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.1/29 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.2
```

like that its working properly. its taking traffic ascending order(192.168.0.3,192.168.0.2) in same thing i try to configure centos 6 its running decending order example

(192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3). now < i want to know meaning of --every 3 or 4 >

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods. It's really statistics. The first method (as by OP) leads to:

- 1/4 (`--every 4`) gets first choice
- 1/3 (`--every 3`) of remaining gets 2nd choice

There are only two rules in OP's question but one can assume two more (or one more plus default) would follow:

- 1/2 of remaining gets 3rd choice
- remaining gets 4th choice

As iptables' *nat* table is handling only the initial packet of a flow, the whole flow will then follow the rule of the initial packet (other packets in the same flow are handled directly by *conntrack* and not seen by the *nat* table).

Each choice got 1/4:

- 1/4 = 1/4
- 1/3  * (1 - 1/4) = 1/4

And for the remaining half (if more rules are used):

- 1/2 * (1 - 2 * 1/4) = 1/4
- 1 * (1 - 3 * 1/4) = 1/4

The other method would have been to use only `--every 4` in each rule but change the modulus with `--packet` with rules similar to:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.1/29 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.3
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.1/29 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.2
[...]
```

- 1st rule gets packets where packet count % 4 = 0 (with % meaning "remainder of division by"): 1/4 of them
- 2nd rule gets packets where packet count % 4 = 1 :  1/4 of them

etc.

The second method might be easier to understand, but the 1st method is easier to scale: just *prepend* a rule with a value for `--every` increased by one if one has to use an additional round-robin.

Comment: ok thank you for the information. i have another doubt . i want to send a first outgoing traffic with "192.168.0.2" this ip second outgoing traffic with 192.168.0.3 in every time. how can i write a snat rule?

Comment: Your comment tell you understand the answer. Then you're asking something that should be trivial: first gets .0.2 instead of .0.3. Is there something you didn't understand in the answer?

Comment: yes i already write a corect rule only  . but some times its not run based upon iptables rules wise.some times outgoing traffic send 192.168.0.3 first priority  192.168.0.2  this ip having second priority. some times its change . thats a reason am asking. how can i run a snat rule.. my request first outgoing traffic wants to go "192.168.0.2" this ip. and second traffic wants to go "192.168.0.3" in every time.

Comment: First begins right after your ruleset was loaded. So it could do a first outgoing connection, then the server is doing nothing for two days, and the second connection will be on the other address (even if it's the first of the day). To do differently would require the use of temporary memory such as the recent match or using ipset. This would require an other question to clarify the problem.

Comment: sorry for the inconvience, is working fine. mail was sent properly with continous ip. after 4 minutes of inactive it take ip randomly based on flow. I want to set ips always in same flow. is there any way to set permanent flow. is it possible to done any other concept?